# Open URL in incognito window

Tags: javascript

I want to open a new URL in Incognito/ Private window when someone clicks on a particular link.

Is it possible through javascript?

Answer (score 11):

Check below

```
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

Solution won't work in a web page, as the windows object is not available there. It may only work for browser extensions.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#Browser_compatibility

Comment: March 2024. The window.create `incognito` attribute seems to be widely available now. See [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/create#incognito)

Answer (score -1):

You can create a new extension

chrome.windows.create({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  incognito: true
});

Answer (score -2):

on chrome you can try this:

```
chrome.windows.create({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  incognito: true
});
```

ref: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-create

Answer (score -2):

Its like you want to manipulate every browser via javascript. Such functionality may opens a door to be hacked for other dangerous commands.

I think no standard browser will allow to be manipulated like this except with designed extensions can call their API methods after ensuring their filters for dangerous commands.

The best option is to open your website in incognito mode and then use window.open method.

Answer (score -4):

Yes, possible through Javascript, But not sure about the Web page's but this will work well for chrome extensions.

But you can't force a user to open the browser in private browsing mode programmatically.

```
windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true})
```

OR

```
chrome.windows.create({"url": url, "incognito": true});
```

Basically `windows.create` accepts an optional incognito parameter.

Won't work in case of a web pages, as the `windows` object is not available there. It may only work for browser extensions.